# How to generate a sample sentence with LSTM model in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'm working with the [LSTM model in Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#recurrent-neural-networks).
I already trained and saved the LSTM model. Now I'm coming up to the last task to generate the sentences. 
Here is my pseudo code:

```
# We have already the run_epoch(session, m, data, eval_op, verbose=False) function with fee_dict like this:
feed_dict = {m.input_data: x,
             m.targets: y,
             m.initial_state: state}
...
# train and save model
...
# load saved model for generating task
new_sentence = [START_TOKEN]
# Here I want to generate a sentence until END_TOKEN is generated.
while new_sentence[-1] != END_TOKEN:
    logits = get_logits(model, new_sentence)
    # get argmax(logits) or sample(logits)
    next_word = argmax(logits)
    new_sentence.append(next_word)
print(new_sentence)
```

**My question is:**
When training, validating, or testing model I have to feed both of the *inputs* and their *labels* (by shifted inputs one) into model via *feed_dict* dictionary. But in the generating task, I have only one input which is the generating sentence *new_sentence*.

**How can I build the right *get_logits* function or full *generate* function also?**

Answer (score 3):

when you train you have an output of the neural network, based on that output you calculate the error, based on error you create the optimizer to minimize the error.

In order to generate a new sentence you need to get just the output of the neural network(rnn).

Edited:

```
"""
Placeholders
"""

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name='input_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, num_steps], name='labels_placeholder')
init_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, state_size])

"""
RNN Inputs
"""

# Turn our x placeholder into a list of one-hot tensors:
# rnn_inputs is a list of num_steps tensors with shape [batch_size, num_classes]
x_one_hot = tf.one_hot(x, num_classes)
rnn_inputs = tf.unpack(x_one_hot, axis=1)

"""
Definition of rnn_cell

This is very similar to the __call__ method on Tensorflow's BasicRNNCell. See:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py
"""
with tf.variable_scope('rnn_cell'):
    W = tf.get_variable('W', [num_classes + state_size, state_size])
    b = tf.get_variable('b', [state_size], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

def rnn_cell(rnn_input, state):
    with tf.variable_scope('rnn_cell', reuse=True):
        W = tf.get_variable('W', [num_classes + state_size, state_size])
        b = tf.get_variable('b', [state_size], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    return tf.tanh(tf.matmul(tf.concat(1, [rnn_input, state]), W) + b)

state = init_state
rnn_outputs = []
for rnn_input in rnn_inputs:
    state = rnn_cell(rnn_input, state)
    rnn_outputs.append(state)
final_state = rnn_outputs[-1]

#logits and predictions
with tf.variable_scope('softmax'):
    W = tf.get_variable('W', [state_size, num_classes])
    b = tf.get_variable('b', [num_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
logits = [tf.matmul(rnn_output, W) + b for rnn_output in rnn_outputs]
predictions = [tf.nn.softmax(logit) for logit in logits]

# Turn our y placeholder into a list labels
y_as_list = [tf.squeeze(i, squeeze_dims=[1]) for i in tf.split(1, num_steps, y)]

#losses and train_step
losses = [tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logit,label) for \
          logit, label in zip(logits, y_as_list)]
total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)
train_step = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(total_loss)
 def train():
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    #load the model
    training_losses = []
    for idx, epoch in enumerate(gen_epochs(num_epochs, num_steps)):
        training_loss = 0
        training_state = np.zeros((batch_size, state_size))
        if verbose:
            print("\nEPOCH", idx)
        for step, (X, Y) in enumerate(epoch):
            tr_losses, training_loss_, training_state, _ = \
                sess.run([losses,
                          total_loss,
                          final_state,
                          train_step],
                              feed_dict={x:X, y:Y, init_state:training_state})
            training_loss += training_loss_
            if step % 100 == 0 and step > 0:
                if verbose:
                    print("Average loss at step", step,
                          "for last 250 steps:", training_loss/100)
                training_losses.append(training_loss/100)
                training_loss = 0
     #save the model

def generate_seq():
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    #load the model
    # load saved model for generating task
    new_sentence = [START_TOKEN]
    # Here I want to generate a sentence until END_TOKEN is generated.
    while new_sentence[-1] != END_TOKEN:
      logits = sess.run(final_state,{x:np.asarray([new_sentence])})
      # get argmax(logits) or sample(logits)
      next_word = argmax(logits[0])
      new_sentence.append(next_word)
  print(new_sentence)
```